# Flash google map like http://online.wsj.com

Tags: apache-flex, flash, google-maps

I want to show flash google map as given on below link

http://online.wsj.com/public/resources/documents/info-FDICBANKS111609_RETRO.html

Can anyone please help me from where can I start?

Is there any ready map available like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a sample [Pan/Zoom Flex Application](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom/) with source for moving around with a Map, which is pretty neat.

Then there's the [Google Maps API for Flex](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/flash/), and they have a few examples and base projects you could use to get started.

TriceDesigns has a [GoogleEarth Flex Example](http://www.tricedesigns.com/portfolio/geoblog/2009.01.01/) ([with source](http://www.tricedesigns.com/portfolio/google_displacement/srcview/index.html)).

And here's some other examples with source:

- [Basic Map](http://hackathon-ashiato.appspot.com/bin-release/main.html): [Source](http://hackathon-ashiato.appspot.com/bin-release/srcview/index.html)
- [China Relief](http://www.flex888.com/lab/grelief/gchinarelief.html): [Source](http://www.flex888.com/lab/grelief/srcview/index.html)
- [Smart Info Window Demo](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/SmartInfoWindowDemo/SmartInfoWindowDemo.html): [Source](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/SmartInfoWindowDemo/srcview/index.html)
- [Orthogonal 3D Map](http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/Map3DOrthogonal.html): [Source](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-flash/source/browse/trunk/samplecode/Map3DOrthogonal.mxml)

I would start with the Google Map API Flex Library, and one of those projects, and just go from there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [amMap](http://www.ammap.com/) for flash and flex maps and charts (there's a free and a pay version).